# Проверка данных при авторизации

Tags: php

Сделал проверку логина и пароля при авторизации, но если ввести рандомный логин и пароль, то авторизация проходит не выплёвывая ошибок.

```
if(isset($_POST['enter'])) {
    $e_login = $_POST['e_login'];
    $e_password = md5($_POST['e_password']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM game WHERE login = '$e_login'")
    or die(mysql_error());

    $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if($user_data['e_password'] == $password) {
        echo "bravo!";
        $check = true;
    } else {
        echo "Passowrd/login incorect!";
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: Ужас. А что, если ввести такой логин: `1'; drop table game; --` ?

Answer (score 3):

В запросе вы запрашиваете только логин, не указывая в `SELECT` поля `e_password`

```
SELECT login FROM game WHERE login = '$e_login'
```

Поправьте запрос следующим образом

```
SELECT login, e_password FROM game WHERE login = '$e_login'
```

Кроме того, обратите внимание у вас две переменные вместо одной: `$e_password` и `$password` - фактически вы сравниваете с не инициализированной переменной.

Comment: Все равно заходит с рандо паролем\логином:(

Comment: @He4ToEnT поправил ответ

Comment: `if($user_data['e_password'] == $e_password)` У вас ошибка в условии

Comment: @ilyaplot сменил все поля на $login и $password и заменил все $e_login и $e_password, все равно та же хрень.

Comment: Ну мы не видим ваш текущий код.

Answer (score 1):

Никогда не вставляйте прямо в SQL-запрос то, что ввёл юзер – это «дыра» для SQL-инъёкций, как вам продемонстрировали в первом же комменте. Вместо этого используйте [привязку параметров PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php), или хотя бы [фильтруйте](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php) то, что прислал юзер.

Вам нужно найти в базе запись с таким же логином и получить из неё хэшированный пароль. Предположим, что таблица в БД содержит три поля: `id, login, hash`:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'dbpass';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die 'Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->getMessage();        
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT hash FROM users WHERE login = ?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $_POST['login']); // это безопасно
$sth->execute();
// если вообще найден юзер с таким логином
// и хэш его пароля совпал
if( $db_hash = $sth->fetchColumn()  &&  $db_hash === md5($_POST['pass'])) {
    // введён правильный пароль
} else {
    // неправильный
}
```